# node.js wait for initialize variable before load other function

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api, initialization

```
request('GET', url_ws).done((res) => {
  if (res.statusCode==200) {
    parseString(res.getBody(),{explicitArray:false}, function (err, result) {
        pdfAnnotations=result['root']['element'];
        console.log(pdfAnnotations);//show value//second
    });
   }
});
console.log(pdfAnnotations);//display "undefined"//first
fn_work(pdfAnnotations)
```

Hello, i have to work with variable loaded from web service, but when my function starts, variable is 'undefined'

Comment: call fn_work inside the callback where the value is available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call your function *after* `parseString()` is done:

```
request('GET', url_ws).done(res => {
  if (res.statusCode == 200) {
    parseString(res.getBody(), { explicitArray: false }, function (err, result) {
      const pdfAnnotations = result['root']['element']
      doSomething(pdfAnnotations)
    })
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

this is normal because the code is executed asynchronosly, it makes the `request` and then executes `fn_work` right after that, while fetching data from `url_ws` , then when it gets the data, it moves on to `ParseString` and so on,

the easy way is to move `fn_work(pdfAnnontaions)` inside the callback of the `ParseString` like so

```
request('GET', url_ws).done((res) => {
  if (res.statusCode==200) {
    parseString(res.getBody(),{explicitArray:false}, function (err, result) {
        pdfAnnotations=result['root']['element'];
        fn_work(pdfAnnotations);
    });
   }
});
```

i would recommend using promises or `async/await` , check these out :

https://blog.risingstack.com/mastering-async-await-in-nodejs/

https://www.valentinog.com/blog/http-requests-node-js-async-await/#Making_HTTP_requests_with_Nodejs_the_request_module